# Нужно ли проверять поля перед внесением изменений, если они имеют функциональную зависимость?

Tags: c#, sql

***Видимо, я не умею гуглить, раз пишу этот вопрос.***

У меня есть база данных, в ней есть три таблицы.[image: 1]

Как видно, две крайние таблицы имеют связь с той, которая находится в центре. Между ними есть зависимость и, соответсвенно, нет нужды дополнительно проверять их в коде **(или есть? В этом и вопрос)**.

Есть код для удаления перевода:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteTranslation] 
    @englishWord NVARCHAR(50),
    @russianWord NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @englishID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[EnglishDictionary] WHERE [Word] = @englishWord);
    DECLARE @russianID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[RussianDictionary] WHERE [Word] = @russianWord);

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Translations] WHERE ([EnglishID] = @englishID AND [RussianID] = @russianID);
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[EnglishDictionary] WHERE ([ID] = @englishID);
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[RussianDictionary] WHERE ([ID] = @russianID);
END
```

Тут нет проверки на существование других зависимостей у какого-то значения, т.к. эта проверка по сути задана отношением таблицы EnglishDictionary и Translations, т.е. если будет какая-то зависимость, то он не удалит это слово.

Ближе к сути вопроса. При такой ситуации, если у значения будет дополнительная зависимость, то выскакивает это:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Translations_EnglishDictionary". The conflict occurred in database "Dictionary", table "dbo.Translations", column 'EnglishID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Можно ли как-то эту ошибку игнорировать, кроме случая, где нужно писать проверку на наличие зависимостей в коде (ведь тогда пропадает смысл в зависимости между полями) или какой-то другой способ, чтобы что-то с этим сделать. Назревает вопрос: **"Зачем?"**, но эта база данных управляется из под C#, а там стоит блок try/catch, который отлавливает эту ошибку. Примерно такая-же история с добавлением слова, которое уже есть, выскакивает ошибка с номером 2627, т.к. поле обозначено как primary key. Не хотелось бы, чтобы они ловились блоком try/catch, т.к. приходится обрабатывать эти номера ошибок по-своему.

*P.S. Извиняюсь за "кашу", надо будет научиться излагать кратко и понятно свои мысли :)*

Comment: Каша. Что вы знаете про `ON DELETE CASCADE`? https://metanit.com/sql/sqlserver/3.5.php "если будет какая-то зависимость, то он не удалит" - можно сделать так, что удалит. НАпример, если вы делаете таблицы через EF то у него есть спец. параметр OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)   https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.2.php

Comment: @AK хех, видимо ничего, пойду узнавать. Спасибо, что хоть направили куда-то, а не палками попёрли отсюда)

Comment: @AK довольно интересная вещь, учту, т.к. в одном моменте она мне может пригодиться в данном проекте. EF я не использую (может быть зря), т.к. я реализовал просто интерфейс на C#, который вызывает процедуры, прописанные для БД.
Но всё-же суть вопроса немного в другом, есть ли возможность просто проигнорировать эти "ошибки", чтобы не ловить их в блоке try/catch, не проверяя отдельно поля на зависимости?

Comment: Есть. Вы про неё сами говорили и она вам не нравится: убрать [ограничения внешних ключей](https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/2.5.php). Все три варианта у вас перед глазами. Другого глобуса для вас просто нет. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Так устроены базы данных, вы просто пропустили эту часть, что задавая внешний ключ вы можете указать поведение при удалении. Пишите руками все удаления. Ловите эксепшены. Просто выберите то, что вам нравится.

Comment: Лучше всего правильность зависимостей определяет СУБД. Собственно, это одна из основных её обязанностей. И если они нарушены, СУБД выбрасывает ошибку, которая в коде C# появляется в виде исключения. Так что `try/catch` обязателен (не обязательно прямо здесь, он может быть выше по коду).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю за ответ, я понял, что обойти систему не удастся :)

Comment: @AK благодарю за ответ, буду обрабатывать исключения отдельно)